# how to redirect specific subfolders to subdomain with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect some subfolders to a subdomain with .htaccess.
On my webpage, i have a lot of subfolders which all begin with "page" like below:

```
http://example.com/page-one
http://example.com/page-two
http://example.com/page-three
```

So what i want to achieve is this:

```
http://page-one.example.com
http://page-two.example.com
http://page-three.example.com
```

I did some research and the way it should work is this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^page-one\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/page-one\.example\.com\/$1"[R=301,L]
```

But doing it this way, i have to write a lot of rules for redirecting. 
Is there a way i can "catch" all subfolders in which the name "page" appears and redirect the complete folder to the subdomain?

Comment: You are managing to grab what comes after `page-one/` already, and inserting that into the rewrite target. So what is stopping you from applying very similar logic to the part before that?

Comment: Btw., `/` does not need to be escaped, and escaping anything in the substitution string is also wrong (that one is _not_ a regular expression).